# Border bottom to Display Under Side Borders

Tags: css, border

Ok, so for the sake of argument i have a box with a grey left and right border with an 8 pixel border bottom with a different colour.

The way borders display is showing the bottom border inside the left and right border. Ive done some research but i cannot find a way that is possible for the bottom border to display under the side borders as apposed to inside them. Sorry if i have not explained this too well please feel free to ask if you need any more information. Please follow the link below to a quick fiddle i have created.

```
<div class="bg">
       <div class="box">
           Box
    </div>
</div>
.bg {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 72%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100px;
}
.box {
     background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 8px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L06s4k50/

Thanks in advance people.

Comment: The border width is relative to the midpoint of the border. If you look a little closer, the top 4px of the bottom border is "within" the right and left border lines. The bottom 4px lays outside of this.

Comment: Your telling me things i already know not answering the question...

Comment: See my answer. I felt my above comment needed to be reiterated, because it didn't appear you knew how borders actually work/are rendered.

Comment: Of course i know how they work :) Just wondered on a quick solution to this. Which i have now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way of going about this is to forgo the `border-bottom` completely, and instead use a box-shadow property:

```
.box {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px black;
}
```

Comment: If you could mark my question up id appreciate it :)